# Can I get Python to evaluate an ValueError input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, valueerror

I'm creating a code that calculates some values for buying a house. It'll be asking the user for a lot of input and I want to make sure the program asks them for integers if they input non-integers.

I made a function that will check if an input is an integer or not, but the interpreter only returns a value error if I input a string. Is it possible to get it to run the string through the integer check function after it's inputted?

```
var=True

print('Welcome to the interest calculator program.')

def integer_check(input):
    try:
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

while var==True:
    num=int(input('Enter the price of your dream house: \n'))
    if integer_check(num)==True:
        if num>=0:
            print('yay')
        elif num<=0:
            print('House price must be a positive number only. Please try again.')
    elif integer_check(num)==False:
        print("Sorry, that's not a number. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Are you sure you included the right version of `integer_check`? This version looks like it should always return `True`.

Comment: [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Surround `try .. except ..` around `int(..)` call; Checking against the return value of the `int()` call has no meaning once the exception raised, because control flow will not reach there if the input string was not an integer string.

```
try:
    num = int(input('Enter the price of your dream house: \n'))
except ValueError:
    # Non-integer
else:
    # Integer
```

Pass the string to the function, and the function should try to convert to int:

```
print('Welcome to the interest calculator program.')

def integer_check(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

while True:
    num = input('Enter the price of your dream house: \n')
    if integer_check(num):
        num = int(num)
        if num >= 0:
            print('yay')
            break
        else:  # Use else
            print('House price must be a positive number only. Please try again.')
    else:  # No need to call integer_check(..) again
        print("Sorry, that's not a number. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast:

```
def integer_check(i):
    try:
        int(i) # will successfully execute if of type integer
        return True
    except ValueError: # otherwise return False
        return False
```

Further, since you only have a pass/fail condition in your main program, change:

```
if integer_check(num)==True:
    ...
elif integer_check(num)==False:
    ...
```

to:

```
if integer_check(num):
    ...
else:
    ...
```